# How to check how many chains and iterations in your stan model have already run?

Tags: stan

Is there a way to know how many iterations in my model have already completed? I'd love to know how many chains/iterations have already finished. Even with `verbose = TRUE`, all I've seen is: `STARTING SAMPLER FOR MODEL` in the output until the model finishes.

Comment: Did you also specify `refresh = 0`?

Comment: I did, @BenGoodrich

Comment: By specifying `refresh = 0` it suppresses the progress reports, so you could omit that or specify it as a positive number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben posted the answer in the comments.

> If you set `refresh = 0` it suppresses the progress reports, so you
>   could omit that or specify it as a positive number